# Bleeding from gums when i do ablution (Wudu')

Tags: fiqh, wudu, blood

What should be done when bleeding comes during ablution?
Should it be restarted?

I have a situation in which when i do ablution my gums starts to bleed especially when i wash my face.
Then i restart my ablution again and again from this state.

I have a question that should i start the ablution again and again this situation? Or i can complete my ablution and clean my mouth at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Allah knows best - and it seems that gum bleed doesn't break wudu. Prophet Muhammad, Peace be upon him, said https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:22:

> "If it were not that it would be difficult on my nation, then I would have ordered them to use the Siwak for each prayer."

What we learn from this is that this is extremely recommended. This can be classified under, considering the strength of the wording of recommandation in hadith, "Wajib minus punishment for not doing it".

So we would all be doing it if we had the same piety standards as our Prophet, Peace be upon him, or maybe as much as the Companions. For every prayer.

We also have clear evidence that our Prophet, Peace be upon him, sometimes prayed multiple fardh prayers with the same wudu.

Therefore even if blood would invalidate wudu (about which I have no idea), the blood from gums is forgiven, because only few people can apply miswak many times without never having gum bleed.

But furthermore as Hanbali scholars considered, none of the many companions is ever reported to ask about blood, and they were correct to be shy to ask too many questions, it's unlikely to have none of them ever bleed, because that's hard to do, especially before this modern age. So to conclude, minor bleedings are forgiven. And this is reliable view, because silence in Qur'an and Sunnah is a well-known mercy of forgiveness.

> ”. It's also reported that he (PBUH) said: “Al-Halal (the Lawful) is what Allah has made lawful in His Book, and Al-Haram (the unlawful) is what Allah has made unlawful (forbidden) in His Book, and on what Allah is silent, is something He has excluded (forgiven), so you should accept from Allah His exclusion (forgiveness)”.

Answer (score -1):

This is the Hanbali and Salafi opinion:

Regarding the effusion of blood from between the teeth, it does not nullify the wudoo' as long as it is minor (i.e. not profuse or a large amount), even if one ejects it from his mouth.

By Shaykh Muhammad Saleh al-Munajjid

Reference:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/1999/small-amounts-of-bleeding-from-gums-does-not-nullify-wudoo

Comment: This is nothing more than a [copy-paste](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953/the-copy-paste-issue-revisited) from the fatwa. We require answers to be written in your own words any claim to be supported by evidences and any external quote to be marekd as such. If we leave out the introducing senetence there's abslsoutly nothing of your own in this post. Note if you are able to answer based on different views there's no need to post several posts.